# Enable mysqlx plugin on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql8

Is there any way to enable the `mysqlx` plugin on an AWS RDS running MySQL 8?

When I do a `SHOW plugins`, it shows that the `mysqlx` plugin is installed, but `DISABLED`.

I have some C++ code that's using the MySQL C++ 8 connector and I want to avoid using the legacy JDBC connector; I already have the code running on a local VM and it's "easy" enough to have setup across the systems I need to deploy it save the fact that it needs the `mysqlx` plugin to be enabled on the SQL server.

Follow-up question: why would I *not* want to enable the `mysqlx` plugin? Specifically, I could not find much (or any) documentation as to **why** it's disabled on an AWS RDS (I presume there's *some* reason why it's disabled by default)?

Side note: if there's no way to enable it in AWS, and my only option is to go with the legacy JDBC C code, that's an acceptable answer, but if it's something as simple as `UPDATE plugins SET mysqlx = ACTIVE` and the only security/performance implications are the same as any other SQL server instance, then I'd rather go that route and avoid rewriting portions of my C++ app.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question since I can't delete it: it seems they don't allow it, though the documentation is not only abysmal, it's practically non existent. It seems as though if it's not explicitly documented to being disabled, it's implicit that it's just not allowed for "reasons".

If you find this page in search of an "easy" way to write "modern" SQL connectors in the "cloud", good luck to you!